# Homoskedasticity and bias in regression

Tags: multiple-regression, estimation, unbiased-estimator

My teacher said "Violations of homoskedasticity assumption does not lead to bias in the estimated coef." Can someone motivate/explain this, perhaps with a formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a linear regression model in matrix notation you have $y = X \beta + \varepsilon$. Assuming a non-stochastic regressor matrix $X$ and a zero-mean error, i.e., $E(\varepsilon) = 0$, you get the following expectation for the response:

$E(y) = E(X \beta + \varepsilon) = E(X \beta) + E(\varepsilon) = X\beta + 0 = X \beta$.

You can split up the expectation due to its linearity and then use your assumptions (non-stochastic $X$ and zero-mean $\varepsilon$).

And then you want to establish unbiasedness of the least-squares estimator:

$\hat \beta = (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top y$.

So you simply take the expectation again, using the non-stochastic $X$ and the expectation of $y$ derived above:

$E(\hat \beta) = E((X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top y) = (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top E(y) = (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top X \beta = I \beta = \beta$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

So you see that for establishing $E(\hat \beta) = \beta$ you only need the assumption that $\varepsilon$ has a zero mean but it does not have to be homoscedastic etc. This works because both the expectation operator and the model are linear.

If the regressors $X$ are stochastic, essentially the same equations can be derived when taking conditional expectations (given $X$). But you additionally need to assume that the columns of $X$ and $\varepsilon$ are not correlated.